# Who is the sender for a SimpleEmailMessage sent inside an scheduled apex class?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

If I have a scheduled job that periodically runs and queries a custom object, then creates a simpleEmailMessage and uses Messaging.sendEmail(), who will the sender for that email be? The user who scheduled it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the user who schedules the class will be the sender of the email. This is true for all asynchronous code, including Queueable, Batchable, and future methods.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick reply!